# How to add post processing on UI (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, post-processing

My question is very simple, i just want to add Post Processing on my Canvas object or UI in general. I know there is an option to select the UI layer but that still doesnt affect my UI. Thanks in advance

And this is what happens when i switch it to Screen Space Camera:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Canvas and change the **Render Mode** from **Screen Space-Overlay** to **Screen Space-Camera**. I think that should fix your problem.

Comment: Nope sadly not , look at the edited question for the picture

Comment: Did you enable Post Processing on the camera?

Comment: Yes because there is post processing on everything in the scene except the UI

Comment: I confirm that switching the canvas to "Screen space - Camera" is the way to have PP on UI

Comment: This is not a great answer. Sure, it "works", but setting your render mode to camera space has a lot of ramifications for your UI and rendering performance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, chage your setting to **Screen Space-Camera** but use these settings (under render camera put your camera):

[image]